# How to pluralize a function's name in technical writing?

Tags: documentation, styles, comments

How to pluralize a function's name such as `foobar` in technical writing?

By technical writing i mean, for example, comment text in source code, documentation of a software or programming element that might be in different place from the corresponding source code.

Should i use

```
foobars
foobar`s
foobar's
foobar
```

?

Comment: If it's comments or documentation why not follow normal english (or your language) standards?  Why change the name of a function in documentation, it might confuse the user.

Comment: Can you give an example how you use this in a sentence?

Comment: Nowhere do you ever, *ever* introduce apostrophes to indicate plurality.

Comment: I don't like it myself, but there are some handbooks that suggest using apostrophes for specific cases like plural lower case letters (e.g. "mark the wrong answers with x's".  This is primarily because xs is confusing.  Other examples include no and no's, maybe and maybe's).  Here: http://www.dailywritingtips.com/when-to-form-a-plural-with-an-apostrophe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest not changing the function/method name in any way as that would invite confusion, but refer to it like:

```
Use the fooBar functions to blah, blah, blah...
```

or

```
Use the fooBar methods to blah, blah, blah...
```

Comment: Op asked how to *pluralize*, not how to specify possesive form

Comment: @Madbreaks ah... my bad.  Why the heck would you ever pluralize a funciton/method?

Comment: I think that's the correct answer!  Meaning, you wouldn't

Comment: @Madbreaks I guess with some languages where you can override methods like java you might say something like, `use the class's toString methods to blah, blah,` if there was say a toString(int x), and toString(int x, int y) or something

Comment: Yeah or if there are several variants of the same method, for example: int add(int x, int y); double add(double x, double y).  the "adds"?  the "add functions"?

Comment: @thang I stick with my answer, use `the add functions` or `the add methods` in your comment's case.

Comment: I think that is fine except that in some cases it may come out awkward because you end up using function or method over and over.  For example, "many of the read functions were written by calling the flush functions and the format functions in between open functions and close functions".  Compare that to "many of the reads were written by calling flushs and formats in between opens and closes".

Comment: Ray, better, removed downvote.  Thx for updating

Answer (score 0):

Add the "s" at the end like any other plural, but distinguish via formatting.

Write something like "All of the `substr`s are...".  I also will distinguish a function name as a function name by using parentheses, as in "All of the substr()s are ...".

Comment: what about variables?  say I use a lot of the variable i as index.  is it "is" or "i's" or "i variables" or *i*s or **i**s? what if you don't have formatting.

Comment: Do you indeed not have formatting?  What are you writing for?

Comment: just playing devil's... for example, a readme file

Comment: What do you do inside a ASCII source file markup/different fonts isn't there?